# Convert javascript expression into a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of javascript:

```
domReady: function(callback) {
        (document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") ? callback() : this.addEvent(document, "DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    },
```

However I'm getting this error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

I'd be really grateful if someone could show me how to fix it!

Comment: When you call domReady pass it a callback function.

Comment: @musefan sure you can, the function's return will be the result of the ternary expression.

Comment: I actually don't know javascript, it's a pre-made script I found online but I think it's a little out of date which might be why it's throwing up the error

Comment: @ASDFGerte: True story...

Comment: Please post the complete code necessary to reproduce the error. It looks like a) this is part of an object literal b) you are invoking the method.

Comment: Here is the full code: http://beeker.io/lab/exit-intent-popup/bioep.js